# Running a javascript file on event

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

I would like to run a javascript file (function unknown) once in a while. Perhaps on some click event. How can I do this?

I want to use this for a twitter update with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1"></script>
```

So this src has to be called once in a while, so I can do a live update, instead of just having a static feed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do script-tag injection:

```
function injectFile(filePath) {
   var newScript = document.createElement('script');
   newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
   newScript.src = filePath;
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
}
```

Which you can then invoke as follows: `injectFile('http://twitter.com/statuses/...js');`. You're free to call that from an `onclick` handler, or periodically using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

It looks like the twitter script you're including is a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) response, which is invoking the  callback function `twitterCallback2()`. You should have this defined in your code before loading the script.

Comment: Can't you use `document.body` to get the BODY element?

Comment: @Šime: Yes, I believe so. I wanted to put `head` in there actually, but I guess `document.body` would work too.

Comment: So you're saying that I should inject this scripts every time I want to call it? So a session of an hour on my website would result in a lot of script tags?

Comment: @Marnix: That's a workaround for the same origin policy (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as the `<script>` tag is "exempt" from the SOP... On the other hand, you may want to use a JavaScript/Ajax library to help you with this (such as jQuery, which is very popular). You could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, using the `jsonp` option for the `dataType` property.

Comment: Which is indeed way more logical to do. I thought about it and I do think that that will do the tric. Thanks!